# Extract a substring from a JSON file in powershell

Tags: json, powershell

I have a Json file with combination of strings, substrings and array as attached below.

I tried to fetch the Id using the psobject and reading the JSON file as RAW but didnt workout.

```
$json = (Get-Content "C:\Users\rasto\OneDrive\Desktop\Job_board\output.json" -Raw) | ConvertFrom-Json

$json.psobject.TypeNames.item
```

Further I tried to run loop but didnt work as well.

```
$data = Get-Content "Path to json file" | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json

foreach ($line in $data) {
     $line.id
}
```

Json File:

```
{
    "data":  [
                 {
                     "id":  "146993",
                     "text":  "value1"
                 },
                 {
                     "id":  "14699",
                     "text":  "value2"
                 }
             ],
    "meta":  {
                 "newest_id":  "146",
                 "oldest_id":  "146",
                 "result_count":  79
             }
}
```

I want to extract the values in field "id" using PowerShell.

Output:

146993
14699

Answer (score 1):

`$data` is not an array, so looping over it won't make any difference. You need to dereference the `data` member of the the root object to get to the array that has objects with the `id` property:

```
$data = Get-Content "Path to json file" |ConvertFrom-Json
$IDs = $data.data.id
```